# Implementing Command-Line Authentication with B2C Authentication (Separate Package)

Tags: authentication, npm, command-line-interface, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a React application that utilizes B2C authentication. My goal is to create a separate package that can perform command-line authentication for the main application and store the obtained token within the command-line session.

Furthermore, I am seeking guidance on how to make API calls to the React app from within this separate package. I would appreciate any detailed explanations or code examples that demonstrate the process of achieving this integration. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For the command line tool, you can leverage the [Device Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-device-code) to authenticate users. This uses the same authenticated session as in the user's default browser, so in most cases they don't really have to re-enter any credentials.

As for communicating with the React Application, being a frontend client (running in the browser) there is no direct way to establish communication apart from using a Browser Extension that can initate it like how Chrome supports [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/native-messaging).

Since that might not suite most use cases, you should instead leverage a server as a communication broker between the two. As a bonus, this setup allows you to communicate across machines.

You can leverage WebSockets for this via [Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview) or [Azure Web PubSub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/overview). The command line tool could call an API that triggers a message via WebSockets to the React Application.